# High TTFB with Amazon S3 (>300ms) when serving small images through direct HTTP link

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm still on my quest to deliver small image assets (<50kb) with low latency from S3.

This time, I opened my bucket wide to public access, and got a direct HTTP link to a 10kb image I have there.

When I open this link with Chrome network tool, this is the breakdown of loading time I get (for the image alone): 319ms total, of which 306ms waiting.

> [image: Downloading time from S3 bucket]

For comparison, a 40kb image from wikimedia takes 70ms total (second image)

> [image: Downloading time from Wikimedia]

How to achieve such low latency when serving small image ? Is S3 just not the right tool?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Possible answer: this is due to regions.

- My bucket was based in us-east-1
- I am based in Singapore
- Running the same test on an ap-southeast-1 bucket reduces TTFB to 50ms from 300-1000ms

-> However this is not a solution, I cannot create a copy of my bucket in each region. And S3 Transfer Acceleration doesn't seem to help.

See below compared speed for us-east-1 (far away from me), ap-southeast-1 (where i am) and accelerated endpoint.

> [image: TTFB depending on region]

**Any suggestion? Serving a static file with low latency globally seems like a pretty basic use-case for AWS, there must be an obvious solution I'm missing...**